# WScript.NetWork is returning an incorrect username. How can this be?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

My username on my computer is `gbrouelette`

*In a DOS window*

```
D:\>echo %username%

gbrouelette
```

I have a simple ASP page which checks the contents of WScript.NetWork

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Response.Buffer = True %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Name Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <base target="mainFrame">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" name="style1" href="../include/style1.css">
</head>
<body leftmargin=10>    
<%
    Response.Write("Session.SessionID is " & Session.SessionID & "<br>")
    Dim objNet
    Set objNet = Server.CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
    Response.Write("WScript.NetWork.UserName is " + objNet.UserName + "<br>")
    Response.Write("WScript.NetWork.UserDomain is " + objNet.UserDomain + "<br>")
    Response.Write("WScript.NetWork.ComputerName is " + objNet.ComputerName + "<p>")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I call this page "nametest.asp"

When I run it on Firefox I get this output:

```
Session.SessionID is 851656495

WScript.NetWork.UserName is gbrouelette

WScript.NetWork.UserDomain is ISOOA1

WScript.NetWork.ComputerName is FCSSAPPP01
```

Notice that the username is correct.  However, when I run it on IE8 I get this

```
Session.SessionID is 851656496

WScript.NetWork.UserName is mktappcss

WScript.NetWork.UserDomain is ISOOA1

WScript.NetWork.ComputerName is FCSSAPPP01
```

And in Chrome I also get this:

```
Session.SessionID is 851656296

WScript.NetWork.UserName is mktappcss

WScript.NetWork.UserDomain is ISOOA1

WScript.NetWork.ComputerName is FCSSAPPP01
```

Also, I noticed that the ComputerName is the name of the machine where iis is running.  My computer is a virtual desktop to a remote computer

*In a DOS window*

```
D:\>echo %computername%

VCSS-DEV1
```

The server where iis is running is `FCSSAPPP01`.
How is it possible for `WScript.NetWork.UserName` to give me an incorrect user name?

Comment: I wonder why you ever get "gbrouelette"...

Comment: Adriano: If my co-workers run nametest.asp on their machines they all get their correct user names.  They are also all on virtual desktops just as I am.  So it is quite an enigma.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion this has nothing to do with the browser because asp is executed on the web-server. so the wscript.network object is also created on the web-server and will give you the username of the user who executes the iis. and the computername of the web-server and the Domain of the web-server and so on.

when i execute your script i always get the username of the user who executes the iis (Default IUSR can be changed to any Windows user in iis settings).

Comment: NameTest.asp is on the server.  When I access it I get either gbrouelette or mktappcss.  But when my co-workers hit the same page they get their correct user names.  My first thought was also that it would show me the server's user name, web server, etc. just as you suggested.  But that doesn't seem to be happening.  For example, another co-worker hits the page and he gets username "tjohston" and computer name "vss-dev" which are both correct for his local desktop rather than the server information.

Comment: We found a possible solution via Microsoft ticket 946358 That ticket suggest changing a registry key which will cause the cache to be emptied and force a new user id/password challenge.   We made the change and restarted our server.  It worked perfectly for Firefox and Chrome but, ironically, did not force a new challenge on IE.   So now I have 2 browsers with the correct user name and one without.